# KDB: delete all variables from memory

Tags: variables, memory, memory-management, kdb

How can one delete all variables currently in memory in KDB/q?

Instead of listing variables manually (I have many of them) like so:

```q
delete a,b,c from `.
```

I would like to do something like these (the commands below do not work):

```q
delete (system "v") from `.
{delete x from `.} each system "v"
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Although this is possible, I would say that it is generally bad practice to do this and you should never really need to do it. Sounds like the symptom of a bigger design/usage problem

Comment: This is needed for debugging/testing purposes. I am working on a C++ application which interacts with KDB processes. During development a bug could occur and lead to a crash of the C++ application or I could decide to kill a test of the application to make some changes to the code, which would leave the state of the KDB process to be not clean. Instead of restarting the KDB process or deleting all the variables manually every time before starting the C++ application, I want to be able to reset the KDB process state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use functional form to accomplish this:

```
q)a:1
q)b:2
q){![`.;();0b;enlist x]}@'system"v"
`.`.
q)a
'a
  [0]  a
```

Answer (score -2):

To delete everything (variables and functions):

```q
delete from `.
```

Comment: Only issue with this is if you have any functions saved they also will be deleted

Comment: This is true. Your solution will specifically target variables only. In my use case, I just want to reset the state of a running KDB process to be as clean as if it has just been started and I only have variables in memory (no functions).